# SQL Between AAA and ZZZ

Tags: sql, oracle, between

I can't get codes that are between AAA and ZZZ, this is what I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE AIRPORT
ADD CONSTRAINT CORRECTCODE
CHECK (Code BETWEEN 'AAA' AND 'ZZZ' AND LENGTH(Code) = 3) ENABLE VALIDATE;
```

It accepts the values I want, but it also accepts values that contain numbers like AB6. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `AB6` is between `AAA` and `ZZZ`. Can you explain exactly which values you want to include and which you don't?

Comment: After ABZ I want ACA

Comment: So - you want to return all the codes that are length 3, and all three characters are upper-case letters?

Comment: I'm afraid this check constraint is not going to ensure a correct airport code (despite it's name).  This only allows 3 letters to be entered.  For real accuracy, do it right and build a table of codes and validate against that.  Some airports have digits in the 3-character code.  Do a little searching, there are downloadable files for free with the data you'll need. Always eyeball the data before setting the rules, despite what the person giving you the specs says.  ;-)  https://openflights.org/data.html#airport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regexp_like`. This checks if the 3 characters are upper-case.

```
CHECK(regexp_like(Code,'^[A-Z]{3}$'))
```

If a mix of characters in upper and lower case should be supported, use a case-insensitive flag `i` as the third argument.

```
CHECK(regexp_like(Code,'^[A-Z]{3}$','i'))
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're just looking for any three letter, upper-case code. If that's true, the easiest way to do so would be with regex, like;

```
CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE (Code, '[A-Z]{3}'))
```

Comment: This does not guarantee that the code is only 3 characters. It will allow a code like `ABD33`. You also need anchoring (as in the Correct Answer, which was posted before you posted.)